# How do I use a job in command kernel?

Tags: php, laravel

I created a job in Laravel 8.x

```
<?php
namespace App\Jobs;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Modules\Quiz\Entities\Quiz;

class SetQuizStatus implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $quiz;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        Quiz::where('publish_datetime', '>=', Carbon::now())->update([
            'status' => EnumHelper::get('quiz.status.published'),
        ]);
    }
}
```

Then in app\Console\Kernel.php I scheduled this job in the schedule function:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('backup:clean')->daily()->at('04:00');
        $schedule->command('backup:run')->daily()->at('05:00');
        $schedule->job(new SetQuizStatus)->everyMinute();
    }
```

I want to change this quiz status if the publish_datetime has been reached. I run `php artisan schedule:run` and it's listed in `php artisan schedule:list` but nothing happens.

.env `QUEUE_CONNECTION` is set to `database`.

What am I missing?

Comment: What is the value for `QUEUE_CONNECTION` from your ENV?

Comment: @AlexanderDyriavin it's set to sync.

Comment: then change it at least to database(Or any other supported queue driver). It seems like schedule not work with sync jobs.

Comment: @AlexanderDyriavin It unfortunately did not work :(

Comment: if you didn't [set up the database as a queue driver](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues#database) previously then just changing the queue driver to database won't work on its own

Comment: Try to : 
php artisan schedule:run
and then: 
php artisan queue:work

Answer (score 1):

I believe handle() wasn't being called when I instantiated `SetQuizStatus`. This fixed it and it now works. My .env file `QUEUE_CONNECTION` can be set to sync as well.

```
public function __construct()

{

    $this->handle();

}
```

Comment: This is problematic if you ever want to use this solution for any job that you don't want to run every minute. It is also problematic because it will tie up the scheduler until it finishes

Comment: Answer may cause unexpected behaviour from laravel and may causes other problems

Comment: So how would you do it?

Answer (score -1):

Do you run horizon? If you sent event to background you need horizon

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).